# Is the conjecture about $E(11)$ and M-theory (West's conjecture) generally accepted?

Tags: string-theory, lie-algebra

I was reading  [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0104081v2.pdf) paper by West, in which it is argued that:

> Eleven dimensional supergravity can be described by a non-linear realisation based  on the group $E\left(11\right)$

From which they conjecture that  $ E\left(11\right) $ can be related to M-theory, too. This seems rather weird to me, given that     $E\left(11\right)    $        is a rather ugly group, given that it has a     cartan determinant of $-2$.       And the Cartan Matrix looks like:

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  { - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1} \\ 
  {}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{ - 1}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - 1}&2&{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{ - 1}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&2 
\end{array}} \right]$$

So, is this paper well-accepted in the string community? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak to whether or not $E_{11}$ is "ugly" but if you see, e.g. arXiv:1308.1673, West's paper is referred to as an "ambitious" proposal. Moreover, West's paper has been cited over 250 times, which indicates it's fairly well-known. (This would be classified as "famous" according to inspirehep.net.)